# Performance issue changing from SQLOLEDB.1 to SQLNCLI?

Tags: sql-server, oledb

A client of ours recently updated one of their servers, and due to changes in TLS (I think) they had to change their client-side drivers. This required us to change our connection string from SQLOLEDB.1 to SQLNCLI.

The customer is now noticing performance issue we never had before. This might be a driver issue, or perhaps we now have encryption we didn't before? Ad-hoc testing using RD seems to suggest throughput has not changed, but latency has.

In any event, does anyone know any gotchas we should look for when moving to SQLNCLI?

Comment: Consider using [`MSOLEDBSQL` instead](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2018/03/30/released-microsoft-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/) -- yes, they like keeping it simple by releasing multiple drivers that all nominally do the same thing but not quite, but that, as of writing, is the most current technology for OLE DB. The OLE DB part of SQLNCLI is deprecated.

Comment: Oh gebus, I managed to not hear of this. I'll try this.

Comment: Interestingly, changing from SQLOLEDB.1 to SNAC on one of my test machines provided a repeatable 5% improvement in performance, so I'm inclined to believe this is not the problem. TLS maybe?

Comment: Or CPU intrinsics, or network characteristics, or the phase of the moon... The only obvious knob you can turn with regards to network transmission is the `Packet Size` connection string option. The default is 4096, but with queries that return a lot of data I've had significant improvements cranking it all the way up to 32767. Beyond that, you'd have to break out a packet analyzer like Wireshark and see what's actually happening (assuming it's a network issue).

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll just save time and hire a shaman.

Comment: That works too. Take care not to accidentally promise your soul to two different supernatural entities. I did that once and it took an entire weekend to sort things out.